# Payout in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Paypal newbie here. I am using the .net sdk to call PayPal's rest api in the Sandbox environment. I am trying to test a batch payout(Mass Payment).

**Issue 1.** The sandbox "facilitator" account which came pre-created has a zero balance. I cant seem to find any way to get some money in the account so that i can test payouts. If i create a new business account, i get to specify an opening balance, but when i try to do payouts using this new account, i get back a 403 forbidden response when i try to payout even though i am able to get a token successfully.

**Issue 2:** Using the facilitator account, i am able to submit a payout request, but its behavior seems to have changed since a couple of day ago. A few days ago, all payout request used to be DECLINED and would show up on the transactions list on the sandbox site. I assumed they were getting DECLINED because the balance was zero. Since yesterday, all payout transactions via the facilitator account stays in PENDING stage and they do not show up on the transaction list. A Payment/Get request for the payout_batch_id always returns back as pending even aftter a day, but theres no sign of those transactions on the sandbox site.

Comment: Can you share the token response you get back when you say "I am able to get a token successfully?" With OAuth2, even if you get a token it must have the proper scope for the endpoint you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Creating a fresh account and giving it an opening balance is correct, and that should work just fine for you to test MassPay.  If you're getting a 403 error that sounds like a problem with your API endpoint or something.  Need to see a sample of the API request/response to know more on that.

2 - Again, need to see a sample of the API request/response that you're getting to know more here.  My MassPay transactions in the sandbox work just fine.  [Here's an example](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/MassPay.php).  You'll see the request and response data there, showing it was successful.  Then when I go look at the separate accounts I see the money as expected.